# Dovecot doesn't use my mail_location parameter

Tags: debian, dovecot, exim, mbox

I'm using Exim 4.72 and Dovecot 1.2.15 on Debian 6.0.9.
Exim delivers emails to /home/username in a mbox file.

**dovecot.conf**

`mail_location = mbox:~/:INBOX=/var/mail/%n`

But -

**dovecot -n**

```
mail_location: maildir:~/.maildir
```

I can't recieve email to IMAP4 client (Thunderbird). Exim4 puts emails in my mbox file in my home directory.

**dovecot.log**

```
014-06-15 16:12:22 auth(default): Info: client in: AUTH 1   PLAIN   service=imap    lip=188.66.5.27 rip=83.139.155.115  lport=143   rport=51531
2014-06-15 16:12:22 auth(default): Info: client out: CONT   1   
2014-06-15 16:12:23 auth(default): Info: client in: CONT    1   AGQuZnJpem5lcgBMb3IxMTExMTk3OCE=
2014-06-15 16:12:23 auth(default): Info: passwd-file(d.frizner,83.139.155.115): lookup: user=d.frizner file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd
2014-06-15 16:12:23 auth(default): Info: client out: OK 1   user=d.frizner
2014-06-15 16:12:23 auth(default): Info: master in: REQUEST 1   18228   1
2014-06-15 16:12:23 auth(default): Info: passwd-file(d.frizner,83.139.155.115): lookup: user=d.frizner file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.passwd
2014-06-15 16:12:23 auth(default): Info: master out: USER   1   d.frizner   uid=1001    gid=1001    home=/home/d.frizner
2014-06-15 16:12:23 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<d.frizner>, method=PLAIN, rip=83.139.155.115, lip=188.66.5.27
2014-06-15 16:12:23 auth(default): Info: new auth connection: pid=19868
2014-06-15 16:12:23 IMAP(d.frizner): Info: Effective uid=1001, gid=1001, home=/home/d.frizner
2014-06-15 16:12:23 IMAP(d.frizner): Info: maildir: data=~/.maildir
2014-06-15 16:12:23 IMAP(d.frizner): Info: maildir++: root=/home/d.frizner/.maildir, index=, control=, inbox=/home/d.frizner/.maildir
2014-06-15 16:12:24 IMAP(d.frizner): Info: Namespace : Using permissions from /home/d.frizner/.maildir: mode=0700 gid=-1
```

Any idea please?

Comment: What is the full path to your `dovecot.conf`?

Comment: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

Comment: I'm no debian expert, but is there where debian's dovecot expects to find it?  Do you get the same result from `dovecot -n -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`?

Comment: Yes, I do. The result is `mail_location: maildir:~/.maildir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we begin, you should know that Debian frequently provides methods of reconfiguring your daemons using the dpkg-reconfigure command.  You may be able to answer some questions during that reconfiguration process and solve your problem the Debian way.  For dovecot, that command appears to be:

```
dpkg-reconfigure dovecot-common
```

I'll continue with the assumption that did not fix your problem.

First make sure that you are looking at the same file that dovecot is:

```
dovecot -n | head -n 1
```

Second, grep in that file for multiple mail_location specifications.  I believe that it's not a syntax error for there to be more than one and it just uses one of them.

```
grep mail_location /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

If you see more than one line that is uncommented, fix that.

Third, it is common for distros to use a modular approach when configuring daemons.  They create a subdirectory that is searched for additional configuration files.  Look in your dovecot.conf for something like:

```
!include conf.d/*.conf
```

I suspect there is a file in there that is setting/overriding your mail_location configuration, in opposition to what you are trying to do in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf.

Why have this directory?  Instead of modifying /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf every time you want to change or add something, you can simply drop a file in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/ named *something.conf* and it will import it when dovecot is restarted.  The files are read in alphabetically according to filename, so it's also common to prefix the file with a two digit number, for example:  *05-hosts.conf*  *29-maildirs.conf*  etc.  So your configuration file is a skeleton with some basic configuration options, and the meat of the site specific configuration is in the conf.d/*.conf files.

Comment: Tnx a lot! I had really other mail_location.